# Add a circle with a number next to a div with centered text

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to add a circle with a number next to a div with centered text(see the image attached for the final outcome that I need).

[image: Desired outcome]

I think that I've almost made it, but I cannot center the text. If you think you can help me or if you know a better way to to this, please help.

Here is my work:

```css
#container2 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.fs1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cl {
  color: #b6ebe8;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 700
}

#a3 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1cbbb4;
  padding: 0 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container2' style="text-align:center;background: #00a99d;border-radius: 55px;">
  <div class='fs1' id='a3' style="-webkit-box-shadow: 42px 2px 21px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);-moz-box-shadow: 42px 2px 21px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);box-shadow: 10px 4px 16px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);">
    <div class='fs1 cl'>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fs1 text-center py-2' style="color:white;font-size:23px;max-width:756px;line-height: 32px;"> Η ισχυρή ιατρική σύσταση αποτελεί τον κυριότερο άξονα προαγωγής του εμβολιασμού και εξάλειψης των χαμένων ευκαιριών.&nbsp;<sup>45</sup></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(edited after comments)

You can use two wrapper elements for that text, where the outer one (`.inner-text-wrap-1` in my snippet)  has `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center` for the centering, and the inner one has a `max-width` (set value as desired).

Note that I also changed some other details, like `display: table;` and `width: 100%` for the container etc.

```css
#container2 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.fs1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cl {
  color: #b6ebe8;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
}

#a3 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1cbbb4;
  padding: 0 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.inner-text-wrap-1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inner-text-wrap-2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container2' style="text-align:center;background: #00a99d;border-radius: 55px;">
  <div class='fs1' id='a3' style="-webkit-box-shadow: 42px 2px 21px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);-moz-box-shadow: 42px 2px 21px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);box-shadow: 10px 4px 16px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);">
    <div class='fs1 cl'>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fs1 text-center py-2' style="color:white;font-size:23px;line-height: 32px;">
    <div class="inner-text-wrap-1">
      <div class="inner-text-wrap-2"> Η ισχυρή ιατρική σύσταση αποτελεί τον κυριότερο άξονα προαγωγής του εμβολιασμού και εξάλειψης των χαμένων ευκαιριών.&nbsp;<sup>45</sup></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want isto make it responsive and  give the div with the text a max-width like 756 px and then center that div with comething like margin-auto in the div with id='container2' but that does not seem to work for some reason :/
Adding a padding is not so good I think because I will have to change the padding in every viewport that it seems wrong.I want it to be responsive on its own

Comment: You can use percentage values for the padding, which I did/changed now in my snippet abobe. Those are relative, so they will change according to the width on smaller/larger viewports. (I also  erased the `max-width` to also keep the centering at large widths)

Comment: The max-width was there becasue I wanted the text to llok exactly like the image(in the image it is 2 lines of text and it changes line after the word "παραγωγής". Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I rewrote my answer completely - please have a look at it.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you very much for your effort, it works fine but the problem is that the text is centered inside the div with class="inner-text-wrap-2". What I actually am trying is to center the text inside the div with id="container2"

Comment: More importantly for some reason in Internet explorer the green boxes gets out of the window port and it doesnt resize. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I found that the problem with internet explorer is the display:flex; in inner-text-wrap-1 but if I remove this then the text is not center